# Cannot get a tag in a specific html element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to get a list of links available inside the tag `ul` of [this site](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/mexico/copa-mexico/cafetaleros-de-tapachula-atletico-san-luis-fcfIQtLo/?r=1#ah;2).
The link that I'm trying to get are available inside: `More bets`, specifically:

[image]

all this links are located in a `ul` tag, as I said before, within a div which have as id `bettype-tabs`.

I wrote this code:

```
var chromeOpts = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOpts.AddArguments("headless");
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOpts);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);            
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new Uri("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/mexico/copa-mexico/cafetaleros-de-tapachula-atletico-san-luis-fcfIQtLo/?r=1#ah;2"));
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs"))?.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

foreach(var c in listItems)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.Text);
}

listItems.Where(li => li.Text == "HT/FT" || li.Text == "Half Time / Full Time").Single().Click();
```

now the last line will return:

> Sequence contains no elements

infact the `foreach` print:

[image]

so why the link inside `More bets` aren't in the list?

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Please post the relevant `HTML`, Also, going by your output from the `foreach`, no `li` element has text of HT/FT or Half Time / Full Time, so the `.Where` will return no elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below for getting the link under More Bets :

```
var listItems =   driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs"))?.FindElements(By.TagName("p"))?.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

    foreach(var c in listItems)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(c.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs"))?.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
```

use this :

```
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#bettype-tabs li"));
```

and loop it like you have done it.

and if you want to click on any specific element then :

```
foreach(var c in listItems)
{
  if(c.Text.Trim().Contains("DC")){
     c.Click()
 }
}
```